# JS - URLSearchParams - add parameters

Tags: javascript, urlsearchparams

I don't seem to be able to add parameters/queries to the URL. I'm trying to add parameters to the url. I'm trying to do it with .set() and .append() but neither seems to do what I thought it'd do. Am I misunderstanding what those methods are meant to do. The desired output should be:

> http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&q=some_word

Code:

```js
const url = new URL('/v2/top-headlines', 'http://newsapi.org')
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
params.set('country', 'gb');
params.append('q', 'some_word')
console.log(url); // All good http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines
console.log(url.search); // empty object
console.log(params); // Empty string
```

Comment: `console.log(params.toString())` - the variable  `params` contains an object, not a string.

Comment: I think you are not assigning any values to url.search

Comment: @VLAZ That worked but how would I update the url object?

Comment: `url.search = params.toString()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You meant to do this

```js
const url = new URL('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines');

url.searchParams.set('country', 'gb');
url.searchParams.set('q', 'some_word');
console.log(url);

// separately setting the searchParams 
/*
const url = new URL('/v2/top-headlines', 'http://newsapi.org'); // (relative,base)
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search); // if the url had a queryString already
params.set('country', 'gb');
params.set('q', 'some_word');
url.search = params;
console.log(url);
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
const url = new URL("/v2/top-headlines", "http://newsapi.org");

url.searchParams.append("country", "gb");
url.searchParams.append("q", "some word");

console.log(url.toString());
```

See

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL